# WPF- Foreground color not changing with os theme change

Tags: c#, wpf

I am setting the custom color to foreground property of Textbox, as shown below

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" FontSize="13" Text="abx" Foreground="#FF003399"/>
```

The problem is that when the os theme gets changed the foreground color is not changing as per the os theme. So anyone knows how to resolve it, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're overriding the colour why would you expect it to change with the OS theme?

Comment: I have such requirements that for normal theme the above color should be set and if the os theme changed then the color should also be changed according to theme

Comment: Have a look at `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` and `ThemeResource`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting a WPF application to use the system (OS theme) colours you should be using the [SystemColors class](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference/#PT4).

Example of making WPF buttons use the control brush key as a background colour:

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
      <Border Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
        <ContentPresenter />
      </Border>
    </Grid>   
  </ControlTemplate>
```

If you want to use a different colour when the default theme has been chosen you could use a [ValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295312.aspx) that changes the colour only when the system colour is of the default value.

Comment: Yaa I tried this, but I don't want the SystemColors.ControlBrushKey color. For normal theme the above color should be set and if the os theme changed then the color should also be changed according to theme

Comment: @Raghva see my edit. You can use a value converter that only supplies the custom colour `#FF003399` when the `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` is of the default value.

Comment: I saw the value converter, but I didn't understood how it will be useful for me